# How to repair duplicates in a Git tree

Tags: git

I don't know how, bug I've arrived to a tree like this:

```
X1--X2--(a lot commits)--X25--X26 (master)
     \                    \
      \                    D1--D2--merge (demo)
       D1'--D2'---------------------/
```

Where D1=D1' and D2=D2' and the merge is empty. This tree has been pushed to the server, but I'm the only person is working on it.

Not a problem at all, but I'd like to simplify this tree to a more logical one. Something like this:

```
X1--X2--(a lot commits)--X25--X26 (master)
                          \
                           D1--D2--merge (demo)
```

It's possible to remove D1' and D2' from my tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each commit in `git` points backwards to its parents. Because `merge` points to the commits you don't want to have anymore, you need to get rid of `merge`, not just `D1'` and `D2'`.

To do that, use `git checkout demo; git reset --hard D2`. This will move your `demo` pointer back to `D2`.

Note that you will be doing a **Very Bad Thing** if you push this to the server and anyone has made a commit that depends on `merge`, `D1'`, or `D2'`. Their local history will still have the orphaned commits!

Comment: Just a note: After *git reset*, I had to push with the -f (force) parameter to get rid of the origin/demo. Now everything is as I wanted. Thanks!